# Unable to recognize old interfaces after motherboard update

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

I updated motherboard on x240 computer node, now the ethernet interfaces show up as eth2 and eth3 previously it was eth0 and eth1.

I tried to delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file but the problem still persists. On boot it says that eth3 and eth2 cannot be recognized or mapped. The new mac addresses are clearly illustrated and mapped to name files eth2 and eth3.

I did change in file ifcfg eth2 and eth3 and change its name to eth0 and eth1 respectively. But this too had little effect, do I need this change to be done in `70-persistent` file as well? I.e. change name to match the entry in `ifcfg`?.

Is there a way i can bring the old mapping back? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Now suppose you want to rename eth2 as eth0 then :

Open /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules with your favorite editor and Do below changes

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth2", NAME="eth0"
```

Note:- if that rule file does not exists then just create it, and replace "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" with your NIC mac address.

after doing change just run Or if you are using Ubuntu then reboot the system because below command work and tested in CentOS:

```
udevtrigger
```

then check using :

```
ifconfig -a
```

then configure RHEL/CentOS = "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" Or
Ubuntu = "/etc/network/interfaces"

Comment: Tried but didn't worked

Comment: @asadz have you rebooted system ?

Comment: @asadz also please update of output what you have done changes

Comment: Udevtrigger was said as unrecognised

Comment: in Ubuntu , you need to reboot , as I mentioned.. , so you did that ?

Comment: but also do not forget to update `ifcfg-eth0`

Comment: Or 'udevadm trigger' if udevtrigger command is not available

Answer (score 0):

Make a Bridge:

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
bridge-ports eth2
bridge-stp off 
bridge-fd 0

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet dhcp
  bridge-ports eth3
  bridge-stp off 
  bridge-fd 0

Comment: Can you explain why that would help?

Comment: what does net.ifnames=0 do in /etc/default/grub 
at GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT ?